# Android NativeScript Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I am a newbie in NativeScript, I am trying to import/open an existing NatriveScript project on Visual Studio code, I have installed, Node, NativeScript 3.0.3, when I try to build or run the project I get this from debug console

```
[NativeScriptCli] execute: tns --analyticsClient VSCode --version
[NSDebugAdapter] Using tns CLI v3.0.3 on path 'tns'
[NSDebugAdapter] Running tns command...
[NativeScriptCli] execute: tns --analyticsClient VSCode debug android --no-client --watch 
[NSDebugAdapter] Watching the tns CLI output to receive a connection token
Searching for devices...
Executing before-prepare hook from c:\Dev\QAP\Mobile app\hooks\before-prepare\nativescript-dev-android-snapshot.js
[31;1mPath must be a string. Received undefined
[NSDebugAdapter] The tns command finished its execution with code 127.
Error: Unknown signal: SIGQUIT
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "tns-template-hello-world-ts",
  "main": "app.js",
  "version": "2.4.0",
  "author": "Telerik <support@telerik.com>",
  "description": "Nativescript hello-world-ts project template",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "keywords": [
    "telerik",
    "mobile",
    "nativescript",
    "{N}",
    "tns",
    "appbuilder",
    "template"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:NativeScript/template-hello-world-ts.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ts/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ts",
  "android": {
    "v8Flags": "--expose_gc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.11.2",
    "nativescript-background-http": "^2.5.1",
    "nativescript-camera": "0.0.8",
    "nativescript-checkbox": "^1.2.2",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^1.4.0",
    "nativescript-floatingactionbutton": "^2.1.3",
    "nativescript-fresco": "^1.0.13",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^2.4.1",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.2.1",
    "nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^1.1.9",
    "nativescript-social-share": "^1.3.1",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^0.2.4",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^0.2.1",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.5",
    "nativescript-videoplayer": "^1.1.4",
    "nativescript-videorecorder": "^1.3.4",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*"
  }
}
```

and my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Launch on Android",
            "type": "nativescript",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "appRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "watch": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach on Android",
            "type": "nativescript",
            "request": "attach",
            "platform": "android",
            "appRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "watch": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: tried re-adding android platform ?

Comment: @HardikVaghani When running tns platform remove android I get spawn gradlew.bat ENOENT
# platform remove

┌───────┬──────────┐
│ Usage │ Synopsis │
│       │
└───────┴──────────┘

General | $ tns platform remove android

Removes the selected platform from the platforms that the project currently targets. After removing the target platform, you can no longer build and deploy your
app on devices which run on the platform.

Comment: What about just deleting the `platforms` dir? the tns platform remove command relies on the platforms directory having been properly setup in the first place. If the npm package was corrupted, or something happened mid-extraction you won't be able to `tns platform remove android` it.

Comment: I have downgraded my NativeScript, this is hat I get, Processing node_modules failed. Exception: Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 22 or later. I have installed android SDK, set up the android home variable

Comment: Roger, make sure to also export `platform-tools` and `tools` relative to your ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Hi @pkanev I have added them to the path...